# Reading the last line from dynamically updating txt file

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a small flask app that writes some output to a txt file while running. Is it possible to read the updating last lines from the same file? I'm guessing that it's possible with JS?

Multiprocessing didn't work for reading the file some reason. Here is the traceback when I tried multiprocessing:

```html
Process Process-2:
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self.run()
  File "app.py", line 24, in read
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "app.py", line 24, in read
    pose = subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', 'pose.txt'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    pose = subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', 'pose.txt'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    data = _eintr_retry_call(os.read, errpipe_read, 1048576)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
    errread, errwrite)
    return func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1312, in _execute_child
    _close_in_parent(c2pwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1207, in _close_in_parent
    def _close_in_parent(fd):
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
```

And this is my very basic code.

```html
f = open('pose.txt', 'r')
.
.
.~bunch of codes~
.
.

if __name__ == "__main__":
 writing = multiprocessing.Process(target=writer)
 writing.start()
 app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Could you tell more about how exactly do you write to that file?

Comment: @Riliam It's just f.write()

Comment: I think, you should save file each time you updated it, or even better to use context manager (something like `with open('file.txt', 'a') as f: f.write('<text>')`) since it handles file closing for you. As I know, this is the only way to make file content accessible from another program.